# How do I extend my text width while keeping the text in the center of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment

I don't like that latex makes the margins really huge. However, instead of changing my margin width, I want to change the width of my text.

I added the following to my doc:

```
\global\setlength{\textwidth}{13.5cm}%
```

however, my text still starts from the same location. So it looks like it's not centered on the page. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have a look at the `geometry` package

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[textwidth=13.5cm]{geometry}`?

Comment: hi, yes I have. It does the same thing as changing the margins. But I was hoping to basically stretch my text instead

Comment: @DanielD What document class are you using?

Comment: I'm using article

Comment: @RDoolabh How can you increase the textwidth without reducing the margins?

Answer (score 0):

```
\textwidth13.5cm % Yes! Nothing more
\oddsidemargin-2mm % to choose manually
\evensidemargin\oddsidemargin % or something else, if they are not equal
```

should be enough.

Comment: I ended up doing this: \oddsidemargin 12.5mm
\global\setlength{\textwidth}{13.5cm}%

Comment: @DanielD Better use package geometry, as was suggested before. The package option `showframe` draws a frame around your text (and ...). This way you can see, what is going on.

Comment: @RDoolabh Exactly as it was: without spaces, without `\setlength`. As simple, as possible.